# How to filter an array within array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have an array of objects containing information about cities and states. I need to filter based on `statecode` and `citydescription` properties.

```json
{
  "stateProvinces": [
    {
      "cities": [
        {
          "code": "T001",
          "citydescription": "Chennai"
        },
        // ...
      ],
      "statecode": "TN"
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

If I pass state code as TN and city description as Chennai I need a following output: `Code: T001`. Tried the following and able to filter based on state:

```js
const filtervalue = getCityNames.filter((code) => {
  return code.statecode == "TN";
});
```

Comment: You want to find all matching or only the first one? You managed to filter by `statecode`, you can get the first element and then filter `result.cities` the same way as you already did

Comment: Is there ever going to be more than one result?  If not then you're really doing a "find" and not a "filter", as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2k5jN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: How would you describe an approach in your own words. Which steps does one have to take in order to find the correct city code by state code and city description?

Comment: Hint the first step was to change the outer data structure from an array of state code based  city items to an object where each state code key features an array of city items.

Comment: @jcalz. Thanks, find is the solution in my case and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way is to use 2 [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)'s.

First find the matching province, then the matching city.

Of course you can do this in a single command with eg reduce, but I think this is more readable:

```js
const data = {"stateProvinces": [{"cities": [{"code": "T001","citydescription": "Chennai"}, {"code": "T002","citydescription": "Madurai"} ], "statecode": "TN"}, {"cities": [{"code": "E001","citydescription": "Erakulam"}, {"code": "M002","citydescription": "Munnar"} ], "stateCode": "KL"}]}

const findCode = 'TN';
const findCity = 'Chennai';

let res = null;

const foundProvince = data.stateProvinces.find(o => o.statecode === findCode);
if (foundProvince) {
    res = foundProvince.cities.find(c => c.citydescription === findCity)?.code;
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: _"A straightforward way is to use 2 find()'s."_ ... it's also the most expensive one in case of a large data structure and a lot of queries on such a data structure.

Comment: Why tho? Find will stop when the matching object is found. Reduce etc will keep going. Do you suggest another approach?

Comment: for a vast amount of queries on a very large data base I would suggest transforming the data structure once into a map of maps ... thus queries then would look like ... `stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('TN')?.get?.('Chennai');` ... or ... `stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('KL')?.get?.('Munnar');`

Comment: Even though a `find` based iteration exits early the time complexity of a nested `find` is much higher then a straight linear access on a `Map` based query path for `Map` is optimized for fast lookups.

Answer (score 0):

From my two answering comments on another answer ..

> *"for a vast amount of queries on a very large data base I would suggest transforming the data structure once into a map of maps ... thus queries then would look like ... `stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('TN')?.get?.('Chennai');` ... or ... `stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('KL')?.get?.('Munnar');`"*

> *"Even though a `find` based iteration exits early the time complexity of a nested `find` is much higher then a straight linear access on a `Map` based query path for `Map` is optimized for fast lookups."*

... and in order to prove the above said ...

```js
const stateProvinces = [{
  cities: [{
    code: "T001", citydescription: "Chennai",
  }, {
    code: "T002", citydescription: "Madurai",
  }],
  statecode: "TN",
}, {
  cities: [{
    code: "E001", citydescription: "Erakulam",
  }, {
    code: "M002", citydescription: "Munnar",
  }],
  statecode: "KL",
}];

const stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap = new Map(
  stateProvinces.map(({ statecode, cities }) => [
    statecode,
    new Map(
      cities.map(({ citydescription, code }) => [ citydescription, code ])
    )
  ])
);
console.log(
  stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('TN')?.get?.('Chennai')
);
console.log(
  stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('KL')?.get?.('Munnar')
);
console.log(
  stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('KL')?.get?.('FOO')
);
console.log(
  stateCodeAndCityNameBasedCityCodeMap.get('BAR')?.get?.('BAZ')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Nishanth ... Even though a `find` based iteration exits early the time complexity of a nested `find` is much higher then a straight linear access on a `Map` based query path for `Map` is optimized for fast lookups.